# electrical circuit with infinite answers

Tags: circuit-analysis

it's about 2 days that i'm thinking that how a circuit can have infinite number of answers.
for example, consider the following circuit:
[image]
for vs=1v & R=2 ohm, if we write kvl two times for this circuit, it's gonna have infinite number of answers, meaning that every ix is appropriate and probable for this circuit...what is happening? does it mean that the circuit is following a random process or something like that?how can we understand what's ix at a specific time?should we use maxwell's equations to find the current of this circuit?
ix is the current of the left mesh and the voltage of ccvs is 4*ix as shown in the picture

Comment: No, there not an infinite number of solutions. Here ix is just linked within the circuit. That can be used to model feedback for example. What you need to do is treat ix as any other variable. So write the KCL and KVL equations down as usual and combine them such that it will give you a solution.

Comment: if i try to write kvl two times for both meshs it's gonna be like this: 3*i1-2*i2=-1 & -6*i1+4*i2=2  kvl equations are the same(i1 & i2 are currents of each mesh )(ix=-i1) every i1 & i2 is correct for this equation

Comment: Please punctuate and capitalise your sentences and proper names correctly. It improves legibility and credibility.

Comment: ok....solve this circuit and give me the answer considering that ix is the current flowing in the left mesh and the voltage of the current controlled voltage source is 4*ix

Answer (score 0):

Like linear systems, linear circuits can have one, zero or infinite solutions, at least at the schematic (ideal) level.

Think of a battery with two open switches. What's the voltage on each switch? Any combination of voltages is correct, provided that \$V_{BATT}=V_{SW1}+V_{SW2}\$. Therefore there are infinite solutions.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqVOro.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course, in the real case, non idealities (in particular non infinite resistance of open contacts) will determine the actual voltage of each switch.

**In your case**, your circuit has NO solutions.

If you consider the Thevenin equivalent of the center-right part of the circuit (central and right branches), your circuit becomes equivalent to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Vv30.png)</sup>

If you write the equation, you achieve:

$$I_x= \frac {-V1 + 2\Omega\cdot I_x-1V}{R1+R3}$$

$$I_x= \frac { 2\Omega\cdot I_x-2V}{R1+R3}$$

Substituting 
$$I_x= I_x-1\ A$$

(i.e. 0=1, i.e. no solutions).

If the direction of Ix were inverted, then you would have 1 solution.

By the way, if you check the circuit with "Circuit lab" (the tool embedded on this side) you'll find that actually it cannot find any DC solution with the Ix shown in your circuit diagram, but it finds a solution, if Ix is defined with opposite direction.

Comment: i'm a little bit confused...you know, it's only about 2 months that electrical circuits(I) course have been started in my university and actually i don't exactly understand what you said...let me say my problem again.i have a circuit like this:uupload.ir/files/pumv_123.png .........when i try to solve thid circuit with kvl: kvl equations would be like this: -3*ix-2*i2=-1 & 6*ix+4*i2=2 (consider vs=1 and R=2) which is saying that i2 & ix could be everything...what's wrong with this?

Comment: You are missing the KCL at one of the two nodes... That's why you have infinite solutions (only 2 equations for 3 branches). You need the third one, which is in fact the KCL. (ix + i2+i3=0 - where i3 is the current of the central branch).